# The FileUpload (PhotoUpload in my code) always shows false

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
if (PhotoUpload.HasFile)
{
     int length = 192;
     int width = 192;

     using (Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap(PhotoUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
     {
         using (Bitmap resizedPhoto = new Bitmap(length, width))
         {
             using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedPhoto))
             {
             graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
             graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
             graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

             graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, length, width);
             }

             string resizedImagePath =Server.MapPath("~/Picture/resizedPhoto.png");
             resizedPhoto.Save(resizedImagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

             string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PhotoUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
             string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Picture/"),fileName);
             PhotoUpload.SaveAs(filePath);

             ImageDisplay.Visible = true;
             ImageDisplay.ImageUrl = "~/Picture/resizedPhoto.png";
             }
       }
}
```

I am designing a page which has the file upload button to upload the file. I am now trying to resize the uploaded image and display it in the asp image box. But the FileUpload (PhotoUpload) is always false even when I select an image. How to fix this?
I am working with asp.net web page, and I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You'll need to share more of your code. especially the event or method where this snippet you shared exists in and parts of the `aspx` page is possible.

Comment: <div class="col-4">   
                                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload" runat="server" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row no-gutters pb-1">
                                                    <div>
            <asp:Button ID="AddPhoto" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control-xs" OnClick="AddPhoto_Click"/>

Comment: can you share the `AddPhoto_Click` method and possibly more of the aspx file? is the FileUpload within a form ?

Comment: Edit your post, and show more of the markup. Obviously if the file upload does not have a file, then REALLY the rest of the code does not matter. I suspect that the markup is the issue, and MASSIVE details say like having used a update-panel is being used here. If you use a update panel, then you don't get a post-back and you can't use the file upload control inside of a update panel.

Comment: <div>
                                                        <asp:Button ID="addPhoto" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addPhoto_Click" />

                                                        <asp:Button ID="removePhoto" runat="server" Text="Remove" Class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm form-control-xs" />
                                                    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with this markup:

```
       <h3>Select PIcture</h3> 
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload" runat="server" />
        <br />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdUpLoad" runat="server" 
            Text="Up load file" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Image ID="ImageDisplay" runat="server" />
```

and your posted code "as is", then I get/see this:

[image]

So, your EXACT code posted does work for me just fine.

So, everyone here on SO is unable to reproduce your error, and even using your posted code, the above shows your code works just fine.

As noted, this means that you are missing additional details, since the posted code, AND EVEN the above posted markup shows that your code does work, and should work.

It is possible you are leaving out some HUGE, MASSIVE, LARGE issues that we here the readers are unable to see.

So, for example, you may well have left out some details, say like a MASSIVE issue on par with say Mount Everest that your content is say inside of a update panel, or some other HUGE MASSIVE LARGE issue you are not sharing with the readers here.

So, try the above markup with your code. I used your code un-changed, and it runs just fine.

Comment: Hey I would really appreciate if  you can give me an alternative for using FileUpload. I think some code is intervening. And that's the reason my FileUpload isn't reading the file. I used the same code in a blank web app, and it worked fine.

Comment: By posting code that works, then we can't tell why or what you doing to make the code break.  So, posting code that don't work is quite much the whole idea here. I mean some out of the blue suggesting may well also not help unless we have a idea of what the goal here is. The result is a guessing game, since suggesting something else might not work either, right? Why should we take away valuable time from our family, or even better spend time answering other posts here? So guessing is bad idea, and a re-producible break of your code, or explain further what is the goal here is good idea.

Comment: The code for that specific page has 1000s of lines, hence not possible to post the entire code here. But I do know some code is intervening and not letting the file upload component to read the file.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. The only basic issue to keep in mind here is that a standard up-load control dropped into a page needs a valid post-back of the page, and such file upload controls can't be say placed inside of a update panel. You have to create a test page, toss in that code, and then start breaking out parts of the markup that stops the post-back and file upload control from working. My best guess would be that a up-date panel exists, since file upload don't work inside a update panel. However, as I stated - I'm guessing at this point in time.

Comment: Another guess? If you have any other post-back, then any additional post-back means the file upload is now gone. In other words, the "first" post-back after the file upload been selected is valid. Any additional post-backs, and the file upload is now not valid.